# Proving Fourier transform operation in Python

Tags: python, fft

I have an expression in the time domain

```
f = -1j*H(t) * exp(-(1j*a+b)*t)
```

which can be Fourier transformed analytically using [known properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms) (`H` is the Heaviside step function). The result of this FT operation is

```
F = (w-a-1j*b)/((w-a)**2+b**2)
```

where `w` is frequency.

Now I'm using the tips in [this article](http://www.cbcity.de/die-fft-mit-python-einfach-erklaert) to do numerical Fourier transform on `f` in Python, and confirm that I do get the same analytical result `F`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-10,10,1e4) # time
w = np.linspace(-10,10,1e4) # frequency

b = 0.1
a = 1

H = lambda x: 1*(x>0) # heaviside function

# function in time
f = -1j*H(t)*np.exp(-(1j*a+b)*t)

# function in frequency (analytical work)
F = (w-a-1j*b)/((w-a)**2+b**2)

hann = np.hanning(len(t))  # hanning window

# function in frequency (numerical work)
F2 = 2/len(t)*np.fft.fft(hann*f)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(w,F.real,'b',label='analytical')
plt.plot(w,F2.real,'b--',label='fft')
plt.xlabel(r'$\omega$')
plt.ylabel(r'Re($F(\omega)$)')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(w,F.imag,'g',label='analytical')
plt.plot(w,F2.imag,'g--',label='fft')
plt.xlabel(r'$\omega$')
plt.ylabel(r'Im($F(\omega)$)')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

However Python's FFT function seems to give me something completely wrong. This is evident when `F` and `F2` are plotted.

**Edit:** Here are the plots...

[image]

[image]

It's not obvious in these figures, but if you zoom in around the `w=-10` and `10` areas, there are small oscillations, possibly due to the `fft` algorithm.

Comment: Can you post the plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT algorithm computes the DFT, which has the origin (both spatial and in frequency domain) on the first sample. You need to shift your signal (after applying the Hanning window) so that t=0 is the leftmost sample, and after computing the FFT you have to do the inverse shift.

MATLAB has `ifftshift` and `fftshift`, which implement those two shifts. NumPy must have similar functions.

Another issue with your code is that you compute the DFT, and plot it at the locations given by the `w` that you computed, but is unrelated to the actual frequencies at which the DFT is computed.

Here is your code, translated to MATLAB, and fixed to properly compute `F2` and `w` *. I hope this is useful. One thing to note is that your `F` does not match `F2`, I am confident that this is not due to an error in `F2`, but an error in your computation of `F`. The shapes are similar, but `F` is scaled differently and mirrored.

```matlab
N = 1e3;
t = linspace(-100,100,N); % time
Fs = 1/(t(2)-t(1));
w = Fs * (-floor(N/2):floor((N-1)/2)) / N; % NOTE proper frequencies

b = 0.1;
a = 1;

H = @(x)1*(x>0); % Heaviside function

% function in time
f = -1j*H(t).*exp(-(1j*a+b)*t);

% function in frequency (analytical work)
F = (w-a-1j*b)./((w-a).^2+b.^2);

% hanning window
hann = 0.5*(1-cos(2*pi*linspace(0,1,N)));

% function in frequency (numerical work)
F2 = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(hann.*f))); % NOTE shifting of origin

figure

subplot(2,1,1), hold on
plot(w,real(F),'b-')
plot(w,real(F2),'r-')
xlabel('\omega')
ylabel('Re(F(\omega))')
legend({'analytical','fft'},'Location','best')

subplot(2,1,2), hold on
plot(w,imag(F),'b-')
plot(w,imag(F2),'r-')
xlabel('\omega')
ylabel('Im(F(\omega))')
legend({'analytical','fft'},'Location','best')
```

[image: output of code]

<sup>Footnote:

* I also changed the colors, MATLAB's green is too light.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for you to write your solution in Matlab code using my `f` function? I'm not really familiar with FFTs in any programming language, Python or Matlab.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata: I have updated the answer with MATLAB code, and some more findings.