# Do Fourier Transformation using Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm trying to do Fourier transformation using Python.

There is nice library `numpy` that have the function `fft` that supposed according the doc to get series of dots and return the Fourier transformation of them.

Now I try to make it work - but it's looking wrong...

I created simple `sine wave 1Hz` , `Amplitude=1`.
I sample it with `8Hz` (so 8 samples)

These are the samples:

`[0,0.707,1,0.707,0,-0.707,-1,-0.707]`

Now I expect to get in return the ens. `[0,4,0,0,0,0,0,4]` or `[0,8,0,0]` that represents that the frequency is `1Hz` (depends if it's does the trimming needed according to Nyquist limit).

But in reality I get the following:

```
[0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, -2.22044605e-16-3.99969798e+00j,
 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, -2.22044605e-16+3.02022804e-04j,
 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,  2.22044605e-16-3.02022804e-04j,
 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,  2.22044605e-16+3.99969798e+00j]
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy
signal = numpy.array([0,0.707,1,0.707,0,-0.707,-1,-0.707], dtype=float)
f =  numpy.fft.fft(signal)
print (f)
```

Why am I getting this results? What I do wrong?

Comment: Try cos rather than sin.

Comment: *"These are the samples: [0,0.707,1,0.707,0,-0.707,-1,-0.707]"*  If you replace `0.707` with the more accurate value `np.sqrt(2)/2`, you'll reduce the numerical noise significantly.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Out of curiosity, why would that help the OP?

Comment: @tel it would remove the 90-degree phase shift which is causing the OP's output to be imaginary (numerical issues notwithstanding).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Makes sense, and thanks. This question has been quite the refresher for physics 201.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving Fourier transform operation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130327/proving-fourier-transform-operation-in-python)

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51204565/7328782

Answer (score 1):

## The output of a Fourier transform

The output of `nummpy.fft.fft` (and every other Fourier transform method) has a complex value. This output encodes information about both the amplitude and phase shift of every frequency component in the input. The complex numbers that you're getting in your output are correct.

## How to get the frequency spectrum from the output of `fft.fft`

From your examples, the output that you seem to be trying to get is actually the frequency spectrum (technically, the [energy spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Definition)). You can calculate this by just taking the absolute value of the result returned from `numpy.fft.fft`:

```
import numpy
signal = numpy.array([0,0.707,1,0.707,0,-0.707,-1,-0.707], dtype=float)
f =  numpy.fft.fft(signal)
print(np.abs(f))
```

Output:

```
[0.00000000e+00 3.99969798e+00 0.00000000e+00 3.02022804e-04
 0.00000000e+00 3.02022804e-04 0.00000000e+00 3.99969798e+00]
```

which is exactly what you expected, within some numerical inaccuracy.

As per Warren Weckesser's comment, you can reduce the numerical inaccuracy somewhat by using the "real" value of `2**.5/2` in place of your shorthand `.707`s:

```
signal = numpy.array([0, 2**.5/2, 1, 2**.5/2, 0, -2**.5/2, -1, -2**.5/2])
f =  numpy.fft.fft(signal)
print(np.abs(f))
```

Output:

```
[0.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.22044605e-16
 0.00000000e+00 2.22044605e-16 0.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00]
```

The absolute value of a complex number is its magnitude. As per the [Fourier transform wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Alternatives):

> the magnitude of the Fourier transform at a point is how much frequency content there is

Comment: Taking the absolute value *seemingly* solves the problem, but is not correct and does not generalize to other input functions. The problem is a wrong expectation of OP for where the origin of the input signal is (and also the output). See the proposed duplicate question.